# Is a claim on email address good enough for permissions with OAuth

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, openid

OAuth is a great framework for allowing delegated authentication so users don't need a new username and password to use your site. However I'm a little hazy on how to store a user who has been authenticated by OAuth so that you can do application level permissions on that user.

OAuth returns some claims about a user including a claimed identifier and email. Up until now I have been using the claimed identifier as the unique identifier for a user authenticated by OAuth but there are some issues with doing this.

- Google gives a different claimed identifier for each url you use to sign in.
- Each provider will give a different identifier for the same person (Eg if I have an account with Yahoo and Google under the same email address they will each have different identifiers)

Both of these make complete sense but especially the first makes it a bit of a pain to deal with.

Moving this primary identifier to email address will mean that regardless of the URL and provider used so long as they have the same email address I will conciser them the same user.

My question is **if I switch to using the email claim to be my unique identifier for a user which I base my permissions on is this going to be secure?**

Concerns

- Relies on providers validating email addresses before allowing them as an OAuth user
- are providers required to validate email addresses (I'm assuming all the main ones do)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about OpenID but not OAuth.

If you look at the [main providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/), its is okay to assume that they have the valid email attribute of their users (for example, in myopenid.com its optional, however they recommend it, therefor they have the email of most of their users).

Email is a unique identifier and it is a good way to identify a user.

I do not see any security issue of using email as the identifier at your application. However, will all the users like to share their email attribute with your application is a concern.